# My Android can’t connect to my Windows 10 PC’s Bluetooth?

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, android, bluetooth, desktop-computer

I just build the PC 9 months ago and prior to that I faced no problems but suddenly, three days ago when I tried to transfer some pictures from my Galaxy A32 5G to my Windows 10 PC, my phone is showing couldn't connect, but my PC is paired up with my phone.

I tried everything from reinstalling my drivers to changing the Bluetooth services but alas I got no result.

I exchanged some data before this problem but there weren't any problems then. Can someone help me fix this issue?

Comment: Have you tried your phone elsewhere, to see if the problem is with the phone?